# Creating SharedPreferences object outside method crashes app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Why do I need to create a new SharedPreferences object for every method it is used in (like onClick for buttons)? 
Why can't I just create it once in the beginning of the class and then use it from any method to add and remove from it like in the second example? 
If I move the 2 rows outside the method as in second example, when the activity should start (when I go to it from another activity) it crashes directly with  message "The application has stopped unexpectedly - Force close".

Example 1 - this works

```
public class FormEdit extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefData", MODE_PRIVATE );
                SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefEditor = myPref.edit();   
                ...
                myPrefEditor.putString("Key", value);
                myPrefEditor.commit();
                ...
```

Example 2 - doesn't work

```
public class FormEdit extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefData", MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefEditor = myPref.edit();   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                myPrefEditor.putString("Key", value);
                myPrefEditor.commit();
```

=update=
log cat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(620): 
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.devtest/com.devtest.FormEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
    at com.devcom.android.devtest.IceEdit.<init>(IceEdit.java:20)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you paste the error in the logcat? "the app crash" isn't a good problem description :)

Comment: sorry, easy to take things for granted whats happens. Clarified the question so it is little clearer hopefully.

Comment: He's might getting a NullPointerException because of initializing myPref and myPrefEditor before onCreate.

Answer (score 8):

The 'getSharedPreferences()' method needs the context of your Activity, which is created after your `super.onCreate()`. So if you instantiate the `SharedPreferences` object before your `onCreate`, it'll crash.

Do it in `onCreate` of your Activity and use it subsequently.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because once you click once, you have an editor that has already been committed. You can go halfway and do something like:

```
public class FormEdit extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefData", MODE_PRIVATE );

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefEditor = myPref.edit();   
                myPrefEditor.putString("Key", value);
                myPrefEditor.commit();
```

**Update:**

Ah, I didn't think about it closely enough. This line:

```
    SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefData", MODE_PRIVATE );
```

Is going to have problems running before your activity is created. Moving it to your onCreate should help. Make a habit of posting your stack trace when you have a question with a crash though, it'll help narrow down the problem much faster.

```
public class FormEdit extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences myPref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

        myPref = getSharedPreferences("PrefData", MODE_PRIVATE );
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefEditor = myPref.edit();   
                myPrefEditor.putString("Key", value);
                myPrefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: I tried it but the same thing happens, the activity don't start. I´m new to this so it is maybe not possible do reach an object in that way. But it just feels "wrong" to have to create the same object (/reference) in every onClick method.

Comment: ok, thanks. I thinks it's getting clearer now. Should test tomorrow, after some sleep.